# SimHash implementation in R

Tags: r, simhash

Is there an implementation of [simhash](http://ferd.ca/simhashing-hopefully-made-simple.html) in R?

(SimHash is a hash algorithm created by Moses Charikaris which gives similar objects similar hashes)

Comment: https://github.com/qinwf/jiebaR/blob/master/R/simhash.R This might help!